# Excel return same values instead of different

Tags: excel

I have an excel query , which should return the common values based on ID from two different sheets.

For example.

I have below data in my sheet1

[image]

and the below details in sheet2

[image]

The Output i needed.

[image]

Output I'm getting

[image]

Below is the excel query i wrote.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A:A,0))&","&INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!B3,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

Kindly Help

Comment: If you got Excel 365 you can do this using functions like FILTER and TEXTJOIN. With older Excel functions I think it's not posible. Also, remember that MATCH only returns the first occurence, That would explain why you get `A,A` twice

Comment: So how should I write this excel query , can you please give me an answer . Am new to this

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Function in column C is:

`=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;FILTER($J$2:$J$5;($H$2:$H$5=A2)*($I$2:$I$5=B2);""))`

Comment: Am getting error

Comment: @DhanyaJithin What error? Maybe your argument separator in functions is the comma? The formula works perfectly, as you can see in the imag.e You need to adapt it to your file and settings, that's all. Also, you need Excel365 or the solution won't work for you